# how login other account by sysdba in oracle?

Tags: oracle, sysdba

I forget hr's password, but I have sysdba role.

Can I use su hr like in linux.

**I don't hope alter hr's password.**

Comment: Depending on what task you want to achieve you can do `alter session set current_schema=hr;` for example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is really easy to log in as another user, just use the proxy user feature that is available since 8i. Unfortunately it does not work with SYS, but works with any other user. Basically you can grant the privilege to users to connect as another user.

```
SQL> alter user system identified by Oracle123;

User altered.

SQL> alter user hr identified by password account unlock;

User altered.
```

So the password of `SYSTEM` is `Oracle123`, and the password of `HR` is `password`. Now allow `SYSTEM` to connect as `HR`:

```
SQL> alter user hr grant connect through system;

User altered.
```

Finally, connect with `SYSTEM` and its password, providing `HR` in the brackets:

```
SQL> connect system[hr]/Oracle123
Connected.
SQL> show user
USER is "HR"
```

You can use any user for this, except `SYS`:

```
SQL> alter user hr grant connect through sys;
alter user hr grant connect through sys
                                    *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-28154: Proxy user may not act as client 'SYS'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use below command to change the password

```
alter user username identified by newpassword;
```